# NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster (AWS)

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use aws eks community module
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks

```
source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
version = "~> 20.0"

cluster_name    = "terraform-eks-cluster"
cluster_version = "1.29"

cluster_endpoint_public_access = true


vpc_id                   = "vpc-0fdn389749nn348"
subnet_ids               = ["subnet-0da3fni3u849hrfn", "subnet-086eb498r43f5927"]

# EKS Managed Node Group(s)
eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
  instance_types = ["t2.micro"]
}

eks_managed_node_groups = {
  example = {
    min_size     = 1
    max_size     = 2
    desired_size = 1

    instance_types = ["t2.micro"]
  }
}

create_node_security_group = true
create = true
# Cluster access entry
# To add the current caller identity as an administrator
enable_cluster_creator_admin_permissions = true

tags = {
  owner       = "mukesh"
  project     = "eks-security-group-test"
  silo       = "modernization"
  terraform   = true

}
}
```

While using this configuration I'm getting the following error:

`Error: waiting for EKS Node Group (terraform-eks-cluster:example-2024022707134518240000000e) create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: i-0a422c5b84ca1db06: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster`

My node is using VPC_CNI policy as well.
Please suggest me wehre I'm getting wrong while setting up the cluster.

1. I tried giving explicit allow to node for eks cluster.
2. Attahced NAT gateway for private subnet.
3. Attached IAM CNI Policy for cluter and node.